# PHP merge duplicate key in array

Tags: php, arrays

i got response (json) from web service and converted / decoded it into php array.

converted array php:

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => '01',
         'name' => 'ABC',
         'label' => 'color',
         'value' => '#000000'
    ],[ 
         'id' => '01',
         'name' => 'ABC',
         'label' => 'active',
         'value' => true
    ],[
         'id' => '02',
         'name' => 'DEF',
         'label' => 'color',
         'value' => '#ffffff'
    ],[
         'id' => '02',
         'name' => 'DEF',
         'label' => 'active',
         'value' => false
    ]
];
```

expected array output:

```
$data = [
    [
         'id' => '01',
         'name' => 'ABC',
         'color' => '#000000',
         'active' => true,
    ],[ 
         'id' => '02',
         'name' => 'DEF',
         'color' => '#ffffff',
         'value' => false
    ]
];
```

What php function is suitable for that case? thanks in advance

Comment: usually a `foreach` is involved, did you try it out?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simple use `foreach`

```
$r = [];
foreach($data as $v){
  if(isset($r[$v['id']])){
    $r[$v['id']][$v['label']] = $v['value'];
  }else{
    $r[$v['id']] = [
        'id'        => $v['id'],
        'name'      => $v['name'],
        $v['label'] => $v['value']
    ];
  } 
}
```

Live example : https://3v4l.org/ilkGG

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = json_decode($data); //decode the json into a php array

foreach ($data as $key=>$subArray){ //loop over the array

  //check and see if value is either true/false
  if (is_bool($subArray['value'])){ 
   $processedArray[] = $subArray; //build output
  }

}

print_r($processedArray); //output/dump array for debugging
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you have to loop through the array and remove duplicates, Try the given way

```php
$data = json_decode($data , true);
$filtered = array();
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($data) ; $i++){
    if(!array_key_exist($data[$i]['id'] , $filtered )){
        $filtered [$data[$i]['id']] = $data[$i];
        continue;
    }  
}

$filtered = array_values($filtered);
```